# Getting Gnome Ubuntu

Tags: installation, gnome

Is their a way to get Gnome Ubuntu rather then the install disc?

Comment: Are you talking about [This](http://ubuntugnome.org/)?

Comment: yes because on the install via ppa I can't get access to unity and it freezes when trying to log in. 2. There is the gnome software updates and extra I did not get when I follow the install instruction on webup8

Answer (score 2):

Yes There is. Go to Ubuntu Software Center. Search *Gnome*. Install `Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components`[image]
Now in login screen, select Gnome like this:[image]

Comment: so will this include the gnome software center and all that I did not get on the ppa?

Comment: According to my research in synaptic, this should come with all the things of gnome ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install the PPA to get the GNOME 3 Desktop Environment. GNOME 3 is included in the main repositories and can be installed just typing:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

I would recommend purging the PPA before starting, since the PPA has packages that have problems about capability with Unity and could break your session.

Comment: Okay so purge and then do the sudo apt install. Dose the Gnome Software center has the same amount of available and software's as Ubuntu software center?

Comment: I haven't seen this "Gnome Software Center" (and I'm using Ubuntu GNOME Remix) anywhere. You sure you aren't confusing it with packagekit?